# How can I do an HTTP Post before reading the JSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, nsurlrequest

I am reading JSON from a URL and that has been working correctly. This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ProfilesCell: UITableView!

let cellspacing: CGFloat = 50

var names = [String]()
var posts = [String]()
var locations = [String]()
var votes = [String]()
var comments = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ProfilesCell.dataSource = self

    let url:URL = URL(string: "http://"+Connection_String+":8000/profile_view")!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
      print(error)
        } else {
            do {
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                if let Profile = parsedData["Profile"]  as! [AnyObject]?
                {
                    for Stream in Profile {
                        if let fullname = Stream["fullname"] as? String {
                            self.names.append(fullname)
                        }

                        if let post = Stream["post"] as? String {
                            self.posts.append(post)
                        }

                        if let location = Stream["location"] as? String {
                            self.locations.append(location)
                        }

                        if let vote = Stream["votes"] as? String {
                            self.votes.append(vote.appending(" Votes"))
                        }

                        if let comment = Stream["comments"] as? String {
                            self.comments.append(comment.appending(" Comments"))
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.ProfilesCell.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

That code above correctly parses the JSON and the data is returned to the TableView. I now want to do an HTTP Post before reading that JSON and the parameter name is `profile_id` and I know that is something wrong in my code because if I do an HTML form with the parameter, things work correctly.

This is the new code that I now have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ProfilesCell: UITableView!

let cellspacing: CGFloat = 50

var names = [String]()
var posts = [String]()
var locations = [String]()
var votes = [String]()
var comments = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ProfilesCell.dataSource = self

    let url:URL = URL(string: "http://"+Connection_String+":8000/profile_view")!
let ss = "32"

    var request = URLRequest(url:url)
    let paramString = "profile_id=\(ss)"

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
       print(error)
        } else {
            do {
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                if let Profile = parsedData["Profile"]  as! [AnyObject]?
                {
                    for Stream in Profile {
                        if let fullname = Stream["fullname"] as? String {
                            self.names.append(fullname)
                        }

                        if let post = Stream["post"] as? String {
                            self.posts.append(post)
                        }

                        if let location = Stream["location"] as? String {
                            self.locations.append(location)
                        }

                        if let vote = Stream["votes"] as? String {
                            self.votes.append(vote.appending(" Votes"))
                        }

                        if let comment = Stream["comments"] as? String {
                            self.comments.append(comment.appending(" Comments"))
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.ProfilesCell.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Now with this extra code the URL is still being hit but `profile_id` is showing null even though I have hardcoded the number 32. I also get this message displayed:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

Comment: you're creating a `URLRequest`, but you're not passing it to `URLSession`. You have to call `dataTask(with: URLRequest)` on URLSession instead of the one you're calling now, which takes a URL.

Comment: Yes, use `request` rather than `url` in your data task. But, more generally, if you ever get a 3840 parsing error, it is generally a result of the response not being well-formed JSON. I'd suggest that in your `catch` block that you also print the `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` and examine the contents of the response. If the web server had an error, it will often return some HTML response that describes the nature of the error.

Comment: Thank you a lot that is exactly what was missing